# Cant access internal http server via mobile device

Tags: apache, http, mobile, server

I am running an Apache server (**WAMP** .- Windows / Apache / MySQL / PHP installation).

I am running a HTTP server for some development I am doing. This project involves comunicating with a HTTP server running ***[Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/)***.

Now, all is well until I try use the external IP address from a mobile device to access the server. Then it just times out.

I have correctly setup port-forwarding on the router and everything is accessible from ANY other computer. So the url goes something like this..

```
http://70.12.123/scriptToRun.php
```

To test this, I have connected from another computer on the `LAN` and it connects fine. I have used Teamviewer and connected from a computer NOT on the `LAN`. That also connects fine.

However, whenever I try to use the same url from a mobile device (phone) it just times out.

> Anyone have any ideas why I cant connect using a mobile ?

Dave

Comment: Make sure your apache server binds to your (70.12.123.XXX) IP rather than localhost or 127.0.0.1. Also 70.12.123 is not an IP address, maybe that's the error.

Comment: Hi Pascal - I am sure the Bind is set correctly - after all it works from a regular PC fine. Sorry for the confusion, the IP address I put in my post is just some random numbers (did not want to post my actual IP.) I have put a few bind statements in the http.confg file such as Listen 2048
Listen 192.168.0.18:2048
Listen 127.0.0.1:2048 (as you can see - I bound service to port 2048) but it does not seem to matter which port I bind it to,

Comment: Just re-read what you wrote, So you saying I should bind the service to my public IP address ? I thought that would be handled by the router (via port forwarding) ? Thanks

Comment: If both, mobile and pc, are in the same wifi, binding to your local ip (192.168.XXX.XXX) should work. If they are not in the same WiFi you need to use port forwarding, but that does not always work as expected. Maybe try something like https://ngrok.com/ or http://localtunnel.me/. This works most of the time and is easy to setup. No installation required for ngrok (binary just works out of the box).

Comment: Also re-read what you asked. I'm not sure if Teamviewer somehow establishes a bridge between the 2 computers monitoring. If not then your smartphone should connect without a problem...

Comment: My mobile and PC are on the same Wifi, This is part of the mystery. Logic implies that if a PC can connect to the server, then so too should the mobile. I am not using the LAN address though - I am using the servers public IP address.

Comment: The only difference in the above scenario may be with the port-forwarding. I have set this up on the router in the usual way - but does this only apply to computers connecting via ethernet ? Do I need to port-forward specifically for WiFi connections also ? It also does not explain why mobile when disconnected from the Wifi - using the mobile network still cannot connect to the server ?

Comment: You are connecting from mobile to the PC using safari right? Not some app? If you are connecting through an app and happen to use an iPhone your request might be blocked at the OS level due to not being HTTPS. I'm not familiar with Ethernet portforwarding (and portforwarding in general). Maybe try cross-posting this question to NetworkEngineering or ServerFault @ stackexchange. This does not seem like a programming related problem for now. If you have an android phone can you ping the server address? Or even traceroute it? There are terminal emulators for android without requiring root.

Comment: And if you happen to use iOS you may try to debug what safari prints into the debugging console by following this guide: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-safari-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac - Then you can find a Developer menu item in safari where you can debug your connected (through lightning cable) device. This only works on macOS unfortunately.